# variables are not assigned values ​taken from the graphical interface. PyQt5

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am doing a course project on pyqt5. There was a problem - in a certain method, variables are not assigned values ​​taken from the graphical interface.
When the button is clicked, the class containing the qlineEdit for the password opens.
if the password is correct, then the create method of the Cinema class should work.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Cinema(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cinema, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.placee)

    def placee(self):
        dlg = Create_place()
        if dlg.exec():
            pass

    def create(self):
        name = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        i = self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
        phone = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        opl = self.ui.comboBox_2.currentText()
        print(name)
        print(i)
        print(phone)
        print(opl)

class Create_place(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Create_place, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('cr_pl.ui', self)
        self.closee.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.passw.clicked.connect(self.password)
        self.lineEdit.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit.show()

    def password(self):
        line = self.lineEdit.text()
        if line == "passage5":
            Cinema().create()
            self.close()
        else:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("del")
            msg.setText("Incorrect password")
            msg.exec_()
```

for example, the id variable is not assigned the values ​​from comboBox. or the phone variable is not assigned a value from qlineEdit. I can't figure out what is the problem. please, help

Comment: How do you know they're not set? You have no code that displays them. Note that `print(self.id)` doesn't print the global `id` variable.

Comment: Some important suggestions: 1. do *not* use globals; 2. learn more about classes, instances, attributes and the purpose of `self` in Python; 3. choose names more wisely: there is absolutely no benefit in naming objects with meaningless abbreviations, especially if they are going to be used in different places (so their context will not help to understand their purpose); 4. classes (and constants) should always have capitalized names, so that they can be easily recognized from variables or functions.

Comment: @Barmar
I tried using non-global variables, but that did not solve the problem

Comment: @musicamante
I tried using non-global variables, but that did not solve the problem. The names of classes and variables are not thoughtless at all, I speak English badly and use some words from the Russian language in the English interpretation. And some abbreviations are easier for me to understand. And I didn’t know about capital letters in class names, thanks for the advice, I will continue to use them

Comment: @Barmar oh yes, I did not notice, I removed self, but this did not solve the problem in any way
(I already changed the question, thanks for the correction)

Comment: @Barmar 
 I also tried to display information differently: print(self.ui.comB_name.currentText()).
but this print doesn't work either

Comment: @Programir I understand your problem, but consider two important aspects: 1. this is an English based website; 2. the code used in questions should be easily readable to everybody, not just you. You're obviously free to use any naming convention you want with your code as long as you're comfortable with it, but whenever you expose code to anybody else (and ask them for their help), you should make *them* comfortable with that code. For example, that `g` may be clear for *you*, but it's meaningless and distracting to us; we're here to help, the least you could do is to make it easy to help you.

Comment: @Programir That said, if using object attributes didn't solve the problem, you probably didn't use them in the right way. The point remains, though: using globals like that is discouraged, and we normally don't provide answers that have issues which are caused by using globals. I strongly suggest you to take your time, do the research I mentioned above, and then [edit] your question by providing a valid [mre] that does *not* use globals, so that we can better address your *actual* issue and eventually give you some answers.

Comment: @musicamante
 I tried to fix the code as much as possible. Only the opl variable takes values. Maybe it's because comboBox_2 is in one Frame and everyone else is in another?

Comment: cant try your code without 'cr_pl.ui',